# Regex returns empty string despite working on regex101 python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to do a regex on this string

```
str1 = "/*Jon is @developer & musician"
```

And it must return

"Jon is developer musician"

[In regex 101 it works](https://regex101.com/r/N7l2rF/1)

[image]

But in pyothon it just returns "Jon"

Comment: Show us your Python code.  I'm guessing you're using `search` or `match`, which only returns the first match.  You want `findall`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this.

```py
>>> str1 = "/*Jon is @developer & musician"
>>> re.findall(r"\w+\s*", str1)
['Jon ', 'is ', 'developer ', 'musician']
>>> "".join(re.findall(r"\w+\s*", str1))
'Jon is developer musician'
```